# Primary key scheme

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, primary-key

I'm just getting started with DynamoDB and am not sure how to generate the primary key. Based on my research I see two good schemes.

1. UUID (or GUID)
2. Timestamp combined with a random number

Are these good options? What are the advantages and disadvantages of the two options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DynamoDB, primary keys are called Partition Key. Those two options are good, but it really depends on your case specifically. Here are two good posts on DynamoDB Partition keys: https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/ and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html

Answer (score 0):

Both the options mentioned above are subjected to your use-case. The optimal usage of a dynamoDB's table provisioned throughput depends mainly on two factors:

- The primary key selection
- The workload patterns on individual items

Primary keys can be simple (a partition key) or a composite key (primary key & a sort key). Imagine it as blocks are created in database as per partition key and elements are arranged in those blocks as per sort key.

Now as per dynamoDB official guide, structure the primary key elements to avoid one "hot" (heavily requested) partition key value to avoid slow overall performance. If your application has many users, then USER_ID can be a good partition key which will distribute loads and optimize performance

Consider a table with composite primary key, with date as the partition key. The number of records created on that particular day, say 2018-01-12,  will be written in same partition, with sort key as item identifier.